# Having trouble with Codeigniter library

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, mysql-error-1054

I am working with a codeigniter library called MY_Model.php in that model there is the following function,

```
public function update($primary_value, $data, $skip_validation = FALSE)
{
    $valid = TRUE;
    if($skip_validation === FALSE)
    {
        $valid = $this->_run_validation($data);
    }

    if($valid)
    {
        $this->skip_validation = FALSE;
        return $this->db->where($this->primary_key, $primary_value)
            ->set($data)
            ->update($this->_table);
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I then executing the function with the following code,

```
$update = array('last_logged_in', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
            if($this->ci->users_model->update($query[0]['user_id'], array('last_logged_in', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))))
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You have successfully been logged in');
                switch($query['user_type_id'])
                {
                    case 1:
                        redirect('/candidate/dashboard');
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        redirect('/employer/dashboard');
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        redirect('/admin/dashboard');
                        break;
                }
            }
```

However I am getting the following errors,

> > A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column '0' in 'field list'
>
> UPDATE `users` SET `0` =
>   'last_logged_in', `1` = '2011-04-28
>   21:06:51' WHERE `user_id` = '2'

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
array('last_logged_in', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
```

to

```
array('last_logged_in' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change it to this:

```
            if($this->ci->users_model->update($query[0]['user_id'], array('last_logged_in' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))))
```

Note the array is now associative - you had a comma in there making it indexed.